# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given

Tags: php

The problem i'm having is from the 4th line of code listed below. I get an error that says

> Warning: `mysqli_fetch_array()` expects parameter 1 to be `mysqli_result`, `string` given

I don't have the variable enclosed in `" "` or `' '` so I'm not sure where the string recognition is coming from at this point. Can tell me how to fix this error?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='question' LIMIT 5";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if($query === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); } 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 5";
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)){
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend taking closer looks at your code when you get error messages such as these. When we are first starting to use a new language, we all tend to make careless mistakes such as referencing the wrong variable as you have done here.

Comment: thank you. i was so intent on syntax errors that i didn't realize i was trying to pass the wrong variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have:

```
 mysqli_fetch_array($query)
```

Should be:

```
mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

Also in line 3 you have:

```
if($query === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); }
```

Should be rather:

```
if ($result === FALSE) { die(mysql_error()); }
```

Comment: better `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: thank you! that worked for that errror.

Comment: You have an error. [`mysql_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) worked only for the old API. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)